# Merge items of list based on common property

Tags: c#, linq, list

Using C# I want to combine the items in a list based on one common property. For example:

```
class Merchant
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Value1 { get; set; }
    public string Value2 { get; set; }
    public DateTime? Value3 {get; set; }
}
```

List contains:

```
{Name = "1", Value1 = "1", Value2 = "", Value3 = someDatetime}
{Name = "1", Value1 = "", Value2 = "2", Value3 = someDatetime}
{Name = "1", Value1 = "3", Value2 = "", Value3 = someDatetime}
{Name = "1", Value1 = "", Value2 = "4", Value3 = someDatetime}
{Name = "2", Value1 = "5", Value2 = "", Value3 = someOtherDatetime}
```

**Note: The empty string values can be null too**

Required Output List:

```
{Name = "1", Value1 = "1,3", Value2 = "2,4", Value3 = someDateTime}
{Name = "2", Value1 = "5", Value2 = "", Value3 = someOtherDatetime}
```

Can this be achieved through any single linq query?

**Update:** I have added a new value of type DateTime.  For each name there will be only one datetime(may be null). How would I include that too in the query?

Comment: Sure. You would group them by the `Name` property, flatten the `Value1` and `Value2` properties and return a new `Merchant`. Have you tried anything so far?

Comment: A `DateTime` cannot be `null`, maybe you mean a `DateTime?`.

Comment: @TImSchmelter its value is null coming from the DB

Comment: @nitinvertigo: but then the property is not `DateTime` but `Nullable<DateTime>`.

Comment: @TimSchmelter for a name there will be only one datetime(may be null). It is not required to be concatenated. Actually in your query I gave it as Value3 = Convert.ToDateTime(g.Key) but I am getting error as The string was not recognized as a valid DateTime. There is an unknown word starting at index 0. The input Value3 was 6/26/2015 6:33:43 AM

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
var query = list.GroupBy(m => m.Name)
    .Select(g => new Merchant
    {
        Name = g.Key,
        Value1 = String.Join(",", g
            .Where(m => !String.IsNullOrEmpty(m.Value1))
            .Select(m => m.Value1)),
        Value2 = String.Join(",", g
            .Where(m => !String.IsNullOrEmpty(m.Value2))
            .Select(m => m.Value2)),
        Value3 = g.First().Value3
    });
```

***Updated*** to take your new `DateTime?` column into account.

Comment: @TimSchmelter if there is one more property say Value4(having same value) which is present in all the entries where Name=1 how would I extend this method to include Value4 in the new list?

Comment: @nitinvertigo: i don't understand the question, what's different with `Value4`?

Comment: A `DateTime` cannot be null, what is the expected result if the `Nullable<DateTime>` is `null`? What is the expected result at all? Do you want to convert the `DateTime`s to `String`s or do you want a `List<DateTime>` or a `List<DateTime?>` for each group?

Comment: @TimSchmelter if the datetime value is null in the original list then the expected value in the new list is also null

Comment: @nitinvertigo: if if there are one null and two non-null datetimes?

Comment: @TimSchmelter for a name there will be only one datetime(may be null). It is not required to be concatenated. Actually in your query I gave it as Value3 = Convert.ToDateTime(g.Key) but I am getting error as The string was not recognized as a valid DateTime. There is an unknown word starting at index 0. The input Value3 was 6/26/2015 6:33:43 AM